# three.js - select objects, get object material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to visualize 3d model of a car with three.js, and I have couple of issues(my code is below):

1)
The 3d model is made in Maya 2016, and then exported as .obj and a .mtl files. I want the parts of the car to be selectable( i mean when u select it, it highlights in green color, when you click again on selected part, it goes back to normal color.
I've already done that, but the problem is that the raycast selects all the objects in the path of the ray, i mean when I select door, everything behind it gets selected and I want to select the door only.

2)
The second problem is that the renderer doesn't visualize transparent materials for ex. the windows and headlights. And I've seen some 3d car visualizers that can display transparent materials.

3)
The third issue goes back to number 1. When I select a part, i want to store it's previous material color(before I apply the highlight color), so when I de-select it, it could bring back the normal color, I've put the color of the car paint, which is just wrong because when i de-select windows they go red.

So, here is my index.html code:

```
<code><html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">

    <script src="JavaScript/three.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/Projector.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="left">
        <p>Low-Poly Croupière<p>
        <p><a href="https://manu.ninja/" target="_top">manu.ninja</a></p>
    </div>

        <div id="test" class="left" hidden="true">
         <p>xaxaxaxaxaaxaaxx<p>
         </div>

    <a class="right" href="https://github.com/Lorti/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three.js" target="_top">
        <img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/652c5b9acfaddf3a9c326fa6bde407b87f7be0f4/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f72696768745f6f72616e67655f6666373630302e706e67">
    </a>
<script>

        if (!Detector.webgl) {
            Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        }

        var container;

        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var lighting, ambient, keyLight, fillLight, backLight;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
        var objects = [];

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );


            /* Camera */

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 140;

            /* Scene */

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            lighting = true;

            ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xefefff, 1.0);
            scene.add(ambient);

            keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(60, 100%, 75%)'), 3.0);
            keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);

            fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(540, 100%, 75%)'), 1.75);
            fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);

            backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xe3ffef, 1.0);
            backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();

            /* Model */

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('assets/');
            mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
            mtlLoader.load('e46_red_5.mtl', function (materials) {

                materials.preload();

                //materials.materials.default.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
               // materials.materials.default.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.setPath('assets/');
                objLoader.load('e46_red_5.obj', function (object) {



                    scene.add(object);
                    objects.push(object);

                });

            });

            /* Renderer */

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 0%, 10%)"));

            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            /* Controls */

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.enableDamping = true;
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
            controls.enableZoom = false;

            /* Events */

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyboardEvent, false);
            //window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        }

        function onKeyboardEvent(e) {

            if (e.code === 'KeyL') {

                lighting = !lighting;

                if (lighting) {

                    ambient.intensity = 0.25;
                    scene.add(keyLight);
                    scene.add(fillLight);
                    scene.add(backLight);

                } else {

                    ambient.intensity = 1.0;
                    scene.remove(keyLight);
                    scene.remove(fillLight);
                    scene.remove(backLight);

                }

            }

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            controls.update();

            render();

        }

        function render() {

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

    var already_selected = false;

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();

            var projector = new THREE.Projector();
            mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3();
            mouseVector.x = 2 * (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) - 1;
            mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight );

            //var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,   
            //                        -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,  
            //                        0.5 );     
            //var raycaster = projector.pickingRay( mouseVector.clone(), camera );
            var raycaster =  new THREE.Raycaster();                                        
           raycaster.setFromCamera( mouseVector, camera );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects[0].children );
console.log(intersects)
            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                var door = document.getElementById("test");
                door.hidden =false;
                for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {

    //intersects[i].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );


    //var currentColor = new THREE.Color(intersects[i].object.material.color);
    var currentColor = +'0x' + intersects[i].object.material.color.getHex().toString( 16 );

    if (already_selected == true) {
        intersects[i].object.material.color.setHex( 0x380000 );
        //intersects[i].object.material.color.setHex( currentColor );
        already_selected = false;
    }
    else {
    intersects[i].object.material.color.setHex( 0xccffcc );
    already_selected = true;
    }
}

            }
  }

    </script>

    </body>
</html></code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For your raycaster issue, in your intersects array, you would only want to access `intersects[0]` since that is the first object that the raycast intersects. I do not see the point in going through the whole array if you don't want to select items behind the first one

2) In order to see transparency, You have to set 

`(object here).material.transparent = true;`
I had to do this in order to make see through objects when you click on them, but I also had to set opacity. Assuming your object has an opacity assigned already, then it would need only the transparency flag, otherwise you can also set 

`(object here).material.opacity = some number;`

3) What I have done when I want to 'highlight' a material is I actually change `intersects[0].object.material.emissive.set('#(insert color)');`
Then when the mouse moves of the object, you reset the emissive to `#000000`.
Emissive is better because you're not actually changing the color, just an outward appearance.